# How do "for" loops work inside the 2D List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

**So basically, I've found a code that can import CSV file to 2D list but I cannot understand coherently on how "for" loops work inside the list. Same also to the for loop inside the "if" statement.**

Here is my code:

```
def dataRead():
    with open("Inventory_List.csv", "r") as my_csv:
        myFile = csv.reader(my_csv, delimiter=",")

        global dataInventoryList
        dataInventoryList = [[col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3], col[4], eval(col[5])] for col in myFile]
```

So that I can apply this understanding to my future List manipulation efficiently and wisely.

---

**Full Code:**

```
def dataRead():
    with open("Inventory_List.csv", "r") as my_csv:
        myFile = csv.reader(my_csv, delimiter=",")

        global dataInventoryList
        dataInventoryList = [[col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3], eval(col[4]), eval(col[5])] for col in myFile]


def dataWrite():
    with open("Inventory_List.csv", "w+") as my_csv:
        myFile = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        myFile.writerows(dataInventoryList)

def main():
    while True:
        found = False
        dataRead()
        print("==========================================================================")
        print("Before update;")

        for i in range(len(dataInventoryList)):
            for j in range(6):
                print(str(dataInventoryList[i][j]) + "\t", end="")
            print("")

        search = input("Enter product code: ")
        quantity = int(input("Please enter quantity: "))
        choice = int(input("Add stocks[1] Pull Stacks[2]\nChoice: "))

        for i in range(len(dataInventoryList)):
            if search == dataInventoryList[i][0]:
                found = True
                if choice == 1:
                    dataInventoryList[i][5] += quantity
                    break
                elif choice == 2:
                    if dataInventoryList[i][5] == 0:
                        print("Requested order is out of stocks!\n")
                        break
                    elif quantity > dataInventoryList[i][5]:
                        print("Requested order is out of range!\n")
                        break
                    elif quantity <= dataInventoryList[i][5]:
                        dataInventoryList[i][5] -= quantity
                        break

        if found == False:
            print("Requested order was not found on the database!\n")

        elif found == True:
            dataWrite()

        print("After update;")
        for i in range(len(dataInventoryList)):
            for j in range(6):
                print(str(dataInventoryList[i][j]) + "\t", end="")
            print("")

main()
```

```
~Inventory_List.csv
CS001,Pieces,Hardie Flex,Construction Materials,5,100
CS002,Pieces,Hammer,Construction Materials,4,100
CS003,Pieces,Mallet,Construction Materials,7,100
```

Comment: this is example of list comprehensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above code contains List comprehensions 
you can break through by a simple for loop and append column data to array

```
def dataRead():
    with open("Inventory_Lists.csv", "r") as my_csv:
      myFile = csv.reader(my_csv, delimiter=",")
      global dataInventoryList
      dataInventoryList =[]

      for col in myFile:
         dataInventoryList.append([col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3], col[4]])
      print(dataInventoryList )
```

Simple Syntax Of List Comprehension
variablename=[(data from for loop iteration) (for loop )]

Answer (score 0):

Before looking at the code, **Understand how the CSV is structured:**

- The CSV File has a minimum of 6 columns
- Columns 0 to 4 have some random data and Column 5 has Mathematical Expressions

Diagrammatically speaking:

```
   |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  - - -
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 0 | d00 | d01 | d02 | d03 | d04 | e05 |  - - -
 1 | d10 | d11 | d12 | d13 | d14 | e15 |  - - -
 2 | d20 | d21 | d22 | d23 | d24 | e25 |  - - -
 . |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |
 . |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |
 . |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |
```

---

**Here is what the code does:**

1. The CSV File is opened in read mode
2. A global list `dataInventoryList` is created to store the data in the CSV
3. The `for` loop iterates through the **rows** in the CSV file
4. The data in the current row is taken as a `list`
5. The `eval()` statement solves the Mathematical Expressions in that row and appends the result to the previous `list`
6. The `list` is appended to the `dataInventoryList`

---

The result `dataInventoryList` would be:

```
[[d00, d01, d02, d03, d04, r05]
 [d00, d01, d02, d03, d04, r05]
 [d00, d01, d02, d03, d04, r05]
 .
 .
 .                             ]
```

where `rAB` represents the result obtained by solving `eAB`

---

The easier-to-understand equivalent of the `for` loop in your code is:

```
dataInventoryList = []

for aRow in myFile:
     rowList = [ aRow[0] , aRow[1] , aRow[2] , aRow[3] , aRow[4] ]
     rowList.append( eval(aRow[5]) )

     dataInventoryList.append( rowList )
```

Hope this Helps..!